# Previous definition is here - Ghost File in XCode 4.2.1

Tags: xcode, compiler-errors

I'm getting a compile error in XCode where a file that I've removed from the project is showing up as a Duplicate Interface definition for class 'class_name' and it shows the hierarchy of dependencies and ultimately arrives at the header file of the class in question.  But that header file doesn't actually exist in the project hierarchy.  In the file location section above the header file's code it just shows class_name.h > @interface class_name rather than every other file in the project: project_name > group_name > class_name.h > No Selection

Doing a search for this object type (cmd+shift+O) and global search turn up no instance of this header file existing in the project.  I've cleaned, exited xcode, rebooted, even checked the proj file for instances of this class, but it's not there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the path to the old location of my class in my project's "Header Search Paths" so it was seeing the file twice.

Answer (score 0):

First step: properly manage your xcode `Header Search Path`, delete the unused old Search path
Second step: choose `product-->clean`